# Нужно сделать метку микроконтроллеры и метки по их видам

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки

Для того, чтобы выделить вопросы, касающиеся встраиваемой разработки, было бы неплохо создать метки:

- [микроконтроллеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b) (en: [`[microcontrollers]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microcontroller)),
- [встраиваемые-решения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f), возможно, сразу синонимизировать [embedded](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded) (en: [`[embedded]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded)

Кроме того, можно сделать метки по архитектурам:

- [arm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm) (en: [`[arm]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm))
- [avr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avr) (en: [`[avr]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avr))
- [pic](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pic).(en: [`[pic]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pic))

Comment: Метку нельзя создать на пустом месте. Есть конкретные вопросы, которые в них нуждаются?

Comment: @Nofate Ну вообще, вот [это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417829/Связь-с-matlab-микроконтроллера-pic-через-uart) хоть и плохой вопрос сам по себе, но ему нужны метки [pic] и [микроконтроллеры]

Comment: @Nofate, я создал описание меткам, но его нужно подтвердить

Comment: Я за то, чтобы создавать метки и их описания заранее. Это позволит пользователям, которые зададут новые вопросы, сразу отмечать их нужным образом. Иначе эту работу придется потом делать кому-то другому.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы действительно поддержал метку [микроконтроллеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b) - часто всплывают вопросы связанным с низкоуровневым программированием. Например [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/403963/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba-usb-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc) или [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417024/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-usb)

Answer (score 1):

Метка уже создана, описание добавил сам Lol4t0. Но она пока что не везде используется.

[Вот вопросы по теме, которые еще не имеют нужной метки.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80+-[%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B]+)

Есть еще метка [avr-gcc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avr-gcc). Это ведь относится к теме?

Где было очевидно, отметил меткой [avr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avr)

Comment: [tag:avr-gcc] непременно имеет отношение к микроконтроллерам AVR и gcc-тулчейну.

Comment: @Nofate: а [tag:gcc] имеет же смысл вне avr? Нужна ли объединяющая их метка? Думаю, было бы достаточно просто avr+gcc.

Comment: там как бы свое подмножество, свои особенности. см. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_AVR_toolchain